# Delete duplicates and reroute referencing rows to new master

Tags: postgresql, cte, greatest-n-per-group, duplication

Given three tables:

A `users` table with `id`'s:

```
╔════╗
║ id ║
╠════╣
║ 1  ║
╟────╢
║ 2  ║
╟────╢
║ 3  ║
╚════╝
```

A `purposes` table with `user_id`'s and `name`'s:

```
╔════╤═════════╤══════════╗
║ id │ user_id │ name     ║
╠════╪═════════╪══════════╣
║ 1  │ 3       │ Business ║
╟────┼─────────┼──────────╢
║ 2  │ 2       │ Personal ║
╟────┼─────────┼──────────╢
║ 3  │ 2       │ Personal ║
╚════╧═════════╧══════════╝
```

And a `journeys` table with `user_id`'s and `purpose_id`'s.

```
╔════╤═════════╤════════════╗
║ id │ user_id │ purpose_id ║
╠════╪═════════╪════════════╣
║ 1  │ 2       │ 3          ║
╟────┼─────────┼────────────╢
║ 2  │ 1       │ 2          ║
╟────┼─────────┼────────────╢
║ 3  │ 1       │ 1          ║
╚════╧═════════╧════════════╝
```

We want to construct a query, in PostgreSQL, where we find all of the records in the `purposes` table that have the same `name` and `user_id`, deleting those with the least number of associated journeys while preserving the one record with the maxmium number of journeys while also updating the `purpose_id` of those journeys whose associated purpose has been deleted.

Right now I have a query to find those duplicate purposes using a window function, however the result only returns one of the duplicates and it's not certain they it has the maximum number of journeys (as I haven't specified that in any of the clauses).

```
select id from (
  select
    id,
    row_number()
  over(partition by user_id, name) as dupe_count
  from
    purposes
) purposes
where purposes.dupe_count > 1;
```

Comment: Please always declare the version of Postgres you are working with. `SELECT version()` helps. It would help a lot to provide actual table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements showing data types and constraints). And what shall be the tiebreaker if multiple purposes have an equal number of journeys?

Comment: Gotcha. Will post results of `select version()` from here on out along with actual table definitions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be a single statement with [**data-modifying CTEs**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
WITH blacklist AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM  (
      SELECT id
           , first_value(id) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, name
                                   ORDER BY j_ct DESC NULLS LAST, id) AS master_id
                                                               -- id as tiebreaker
      FROM   purposes
      LEFT   JOIN (  -- left join to preserve rows without any journeys
         SELECT purpose_id AS id, count(*) AS j_ct
         FROM   journeys
         GROUP  BY 1
         ) j USING (id)
      ) sub
   WHERE  master_id <> id  -- is not master_id
   )
 , del AS (
   DELETE FROM purposes p
   USING  blacklist b
   WHERE  b.id = p.id
   )
UPDATE journeys j
SET    purpose_id = b.master_id
FROM   blacklist b
WHERE  b.id = j.purpose_id;
```

This should do exactly what you need - even in cases of ties or where no journeys exist at all.

#### Step by step

The 1st CTE blacklist identifies all IDs in table `purposes` where another row exists with the same `(user_id, name)` but more associated journeys. Remember that other ID as `master_id` to reassign journeys further down the road. `id` serves as tiebreaker: the smallest `id` prevails.

The 2nd CTE `del` deletes the identified dupes.
The outer `UPDATE` reroutes journeys to their new master.

Note `DESC NULLS LAST` in the `ORDER BY` clause. Important for cases with no journeys at all, since that result in a `NULL` value for the journey count `j_ct`. See:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860)

Use the [window function `first_value()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) to get the `master_id` for each group of peers - after forming groups with `PARTITION BY` and sorting properly with `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Wow, thanks Erwin. I am learning a lot from your solution! Though, I should note, that looking at the docs for the `first_value()` window function shows that it takes an argument (the first value of what?) so for my problem I simply used `first_value(id)`.

Comment: @dynsne: Right, `id` was missing.